# Solving two variables with one equation

Tags: problem-solving

I have been trying to solve the following equation, but I am still stuck after trying many different methods.

I have been given this equation to solve:

$$(1 + z^{-1})^4 (a + bz^{-1} + az^{-2}) - (1 - z^{-1})^4 (a - bz^{-1} + az^{-2}) = 2z^{-d}$$

I have simplified it down to 
$$a(4z^{-1} + 8z^{-3} + 4z^{-5}) + b(z^{-1} + 6z^{-3} + z^{-5}) = z^{-d}$$

The goal is to find the values for '$a$' and '$b$' for ANY value for '$d$'. I don't think I made any mistakes up to the simplifications.

EDIT:
I thought of having $a = 1$ and $b = 4$, but this would give me

$$ -16z^{-3} = z^{-d} $$

This is not exactly equal since it should be $1$ in front, instead of $-16$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be:

a = -1/16

b = 1/4

That would give us $z^{-3}$, so d = 3

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are given a value for $z$ as well, but you don't have enough information.  You can solve for either $a$ or $b$, but not both, with one equation.

Comment: You might also simplify the equation by multiplying both sides by $z^6$.

Comment: I am not solving for z. I am just trying to figure out some values for both a and b that would make the equation equal for ANY d

Comment: Thanks for the tip on multiplying both sides by z^{6}, but since I am not solving for z, I can simply treat any z^{-n} as z^{n}

Comment: You still can't solve for two variables in one equation unless something is special like $a^2+b^2=0$.  There is nothing like that here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hmm, I know the solutions would not be unique since there are two unknowns in one equation, but I was hoping for at least some non-unique solutions

Comment: You can solve the equation for either $a$ or $b$.  That is not hard, it is linear in both of them.  That will give you a solution for *one* variable based on the other (and $d,z$).  That is all you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both sides by $z^6$ you get
\begin{equation}
(z+1)(az^2+bz+a)-(z-1)(az^2-bz+a)=2z^{6-d}
\end{equation}
which simplifies to
\begin{equation}
(a+b)z^2+a=z^{6-d}
\end{equation}

You may solve this for $a$, $b$, $d$ or $z$ in terms of the other three variables.

Comment: Solving for $z$ would be the most difficult.

Comment: Now if one were given additional information about $z$, such as there were exactly two real and two complex solutions, that would be an interesting problem.

Comment: It seems that you missed the exponents $4$

Comment: Yup I think John missed the exponents

Comment: Oops! You're right!